# android BroadCastReceiver not working within an activity

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have want to develop an sms notifier. The thing is when SMS is receiced a textbox in the activity just change to "SMS Received" text. 
SMS is successfully sending but BroadCastReceiver is not working, please help.

my code:

```
package com.shahid.todolist;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*
         * SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
         * 
         * String sendTo = "03129912287"; String myMessage =
         * "Android supports programmatic SMS messaging!";
         * smsManager.sendTextMessage(sendTo, null, myMessage, null, null);
         */

        final EditText phoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNo);
        final TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);
        Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                display.setText("Sending SMS...");
                String sendTo = phoneNo.getText().toString();
                String myMessage = "This is Shahid from Android";
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(sendTo, null, myMessage, null, null);
            }
        });

        // ---
        final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            private static final String queryString = "@echo ";
            private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent _intent) {
                if (_intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
                    display.setText("SMS Received");
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to register you reciever into manifest

Comment: You should register your broadcast receiver dynamic or static(in androidmanifest.xml) and set intent filter for your sms broadcast intent

Comment: how to register in the menifest?

Comment: do you want to change the text when you received a sms?

Answer (score 1):

You have to register your broadcast when it is within your activity.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BroadcastReceiver.SMS_RECEIVED);  // Provide you intent filter for message received.
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Comment: @GunahGaar: Check my updated answer . SendBroadcast is mine class where i declared my intent filter

Comment: sorry, what is receiver here?

Comment: receiver is your broadcast receiver class name that you declared in you activity.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone, in my case the problem was that I was using special characters like brackets in my text. Once I removed those characters it started working

Comment: special characters, i.e., non-gsm characters cause the available sms length to decrease below 70. If your sms length exceeds that limit then it is not sent, unless you use sendMultipartTextMessage https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager#sendMultipartTextMessage(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E,%2520java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.app.PendingIntent%3E,%2520java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.app.PendingIntent%3E)